# How to decode responses

Tags: paw-app

I have API calls that return files that are gzipped and then base64 encoded so that they can be returned as part of JSON responses. I'd like to be able to decode those files. At the moment I have to copy the base64 test, decode it and then gunzip the result.

Is there an extension for this or can I create one?

Answer (score 0):

1. copy response text
2. go to `header` or `params` or `body` tab
3. paste copied text any value field
4. select all pasted text
5. mouse right-click -> encoding -> URL-encoding/Base64 -> encode/decode
6. paste text to `input` field

[image]

---

or use [Atom](https://atom.io) + [escape-utils](https://atom.io/packages/escape-utils) plugin